# Do I need to run a ground from my main panel to the new sub panel 100' away?

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel

Do I need to run a ground from my main panel to the new sub panel 100' away or can I establish the ground at the shop location ie. UFER?

Comment: Just to clarify, the required equipment ground you run to a remote panel has nothing to do with the required grounding electrode you install. The two things serve two very different purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run a separate grounding conductor between the panels. If the second panel is in another building, you need to install a grounding electrode at that building as well. At least that's how it's done in  the US, if you're covered by NEC.

Answer (score 0):

The "Ufer" ground can be used as the grounding electrode at a second building but it does not replace the requirement to run a separate equipment ground to the sub panel.

If the two panels are in the same building the second grounding electrode is not required.